# handle OS specific .classpath file in a hg repo

Tags: eclipse, macos, version-control, mercurial

I have a Java project in Eclipse and version-control is a mercurial repo.
From several environments (Linux/Windows/MacOSX) I'm working with this same repo.

Problem is that in the .classpath file I've one line which is specific for the MacOSX environment and differs for the other environments. Still I don't want to put .classpath the ignore flag in version control.

I'm thinking of e.g. a mercurial extension on my MacOSX environment to tell mercurial to ignore this one specific line in .classpath but still sync everything else.

For all other environments (Linux/Windows) it's important that no changes are needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workflow-changing approach would be to switch your project to use something like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) to manage your classpath and dependencies.  Then you can use [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) to automatically import it into Eclipse on each machine and automatically generate the appropriate project settings and classpath.

Comment: good point. currently I've this issue only with one project we have not yet ported form Ant to Maven.